# \chapterprefix different in heading and head line

Tags: sectioning, scrbook

I am looking for a -- on the first glance -- inconsistent solution.
I need the chapterprefix in the heading (\chapter) but I do not
want to see it in the head line (\headmark etc.). I could not find
an appropriate option, but perhaps there is one.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\chapter{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this code in your preamble::

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
```

See page 105 in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf). Your MWE:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    \thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\chapter{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\section{B}
\section{C}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the linked version of the manual (2017-01-02) the \chaptermarkformat is to find on page 105, section 3.16.

Comment: @Jürgen Sorry, I read the version on my computer, which is an older version. I will update.